# How to avoid automatic facebook posts about a game?

Tags: facebook, post

I have made an facebook game with a highscore and it all works pretty well.

But facebook is automatically making post like

*"John has played picman and made a score of 5100"*

Q: Is there any posibility to avoid this posts? I don't want fb to posts this, because in the game not the points but the time is stored.

thx, menaard!

Comment: I don't understand the question - those stories have to be posted by the App, they're not automatic - don't post the score if you don't those posts

Comment: @Igy, as far as I understand it creating scores via the scores API automatically creates a „story”. And there seems to be no parameter to suppress the story … which is understandable, because that a basic part of Facebook gaming.

Comment: This depends if you are the app owner wanting to stop this, or if you are a normal user wanting to stop this in your newsfeed. Please explain?

Comment: I believe he's the app owner, but if so, his question doesn't make that sense; if he doesn't want the scores stories he shouldn't post them

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer on how to avoid these automatic posts (=stories) on Getting Started › Apps on Facebook.com

*"Developers of app associated with more personal behavior such as dating, weight management or pregnancy, can turn these stories off by disabling the social discovery field in the App Dashboard in the ‘On Facebook’ tab under the ‘Canvas’ section."*